# Support other languages in spring-boot-cli

Tags: spring-boot

Regarding the spring-boot-cli and the future of Groovy.

Can someone please briefly outline the roadmap for the cloud-cli? Especially introducing support for other languages than groovy?

The world is moving forward and there is not much buzz around Groovy and Java9. 
In contrary, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/CedricChampeau/status/913334345322156032) by Cédric Champeau is a cause for concern. 
At the same time, Spring Framework 5 introduces Kotlin support.
Gradle already did over a year ago.

So it would be interesting to get the teams view and also some info on where spring-boot-cli is heading.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Discussions such as these don't belong here.

Comment: Well, initially I wanted to post an issues on github. However, the directions there said questions should be posted on SO using the spring-boot tag. Which is exactly what I did.